# Dynamic meta descriptions for certain pages in React SPA

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, server-side-rendering

I built a blog with React that fetches the data for each blog entry dynamically from an api.
The page's content obviously looks different depending on the route, e.g. `mysite.com/blog/1`, `mysite.com/blog/2`, ...

What I want to achieve is to dynamically change the meta descriptions depending on the data that is fetched from the api based on the url. In particular the `og:title`, `og:description` and `og:image`. Is something like that even possible?

I read about SSR/Next.JS or Gatsby but I am not sure if this is working if the data is received from api calls.

I understand that SSR would render the content on the server, hence it allows Google to crawl the pages but wouldn't that exclude api calls?
I also understand that Gatsby builds static sites but for me that wouldn't work because the api calls are dynamic and cannot be built into a static site.

I would highly appreciate some hints to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a pretty good article [here](https://dillionmegida.com/p/how-to-configure-meta-tags-in-react-app-dynamically/) that describes how to work around this issue the easiest way.

Basically, I needed to put a simple NodeJS server on top of my current React application. The server is now serving the files from the build directory. For some routes, I am simply replacing the `__PAGE_META__` placeholder with the meta tags needed for Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc.

Here is a simple picture to describe the flow:
[image]

And a simple code snippet of the NodeJS part:

```
const path = require("path")
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const fs = require("fs")
//
const pathToIndex = path.join(__dirname, "build/index.html")
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const raw = fs.readFileSync(pathToIndex)
  const pageTitle = "Homepage - Welcome to my page"
  const updated = raw.replace("__PAGE_META__", `<title>${pageTitle}</title>`)
  res.send(updated)
})
//
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")))
app.get("*", (req, res) =>
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build/index.html"))
)
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`)
})
```

For the dynamic site, an api can be called and the page meta can be replaced with the information appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that SSR would render the content on the server, hence it
> allows Google to crawl the pages but wouldn't that exclude api calls?
> I also understand that Gatsby builds static sites but for me that
> wouldn't work because the api calls are dynamic and cannot be built
> into a static site.

I think you've misunderstood how Gatsby works.

To summarize, Gatsby generates static pages from dynamic data (API calls) so, when you run the `gatsby develop` or `gatsby build` command, Gatsby fetches the data from the sources (in this case from your API) and generates dynamic pages (`mysite.com/blog/1`, `mysite.com/blog/2`, etc).

This data is static, meaning that each change of those sources, will force you to re-fetch the data to display the changes (in production means a new deployment) but, as soon as your pages are built statically, you can build your SEO data on the fly.

This is an old Gatsby's workflow that they used to have on their old website but I find it quite self-explanatory:

[image: Gatsby's workflow]

In the build-time, your site is being statically generated so, you can fully customize your SEO requirements with a custom SEO component or whatever your want. Most of the starters come with a [`SEO`](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default/blob/master/src/components/seo.js) component ready to be used:

```
function Seo({ description, lang, meta, title }) {
  const { site } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
            description
            author
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )

  const metaDescription = description || site.siteMetadata.description
  const defaultTitle = site.siteMetadata?.title

  return (
    <Helmet
      htmlAttributes={{
        lang,
      }}
      title={title}
      titleTemplate={defaultTitle ? `%s | ${defaultTitle}` : null}
      meta={[
        {
          name: `description`,
          content: metaDescription,
        },
        {
          property: `og:title`,
          content: title,
        },
        {
          property: `og:description`,
          content: metaDescription,
        },
        {
          property: `og:type`,
          content: `website`,
        },
        {
          name: `twitter:card`,
          content: `summary`,
        },
        {
          name: `twitter:creator`,
          content: site.siteMetadata?.author || ``,
        },
        {
          name: `twitter:title`,
          content: title,
        },
        {
          name: `twitter:description`,
          content: metaDescription,
        },
      ].concat(meta)}
    />
  )
}
```

Since the component is taking `description`, `lang`, `meta` and `title` as a `props` respectively, you can add it in your blog template to take dynamic data that will be built statically, meaning that, when your site will be deployed, that data will be already built, so Google crawlers will get it instantly.

```
const YourBlogPostTemplate = ({ data }) =>{    
   
   return <article>
   <SEO title={data.allAPIData.frontmatter.title} />
   <h1>I'm the title: {data.allAPIData.frontmatter.title}</h1>
   </article>
}
```

*Note: I won't fully customize it to avoid extending the answer, but get the idea.*

The `SEO` component will be taking the `title` and the rest of the fields in the build-time.

Your API calls are fetched before the page is built so, at the time your page is being built your data is already static.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, since this is a dynamic blog with people constantly adding new content (therefore new pages), it is not possible to deploy a build each time. I need SEO for each new page that is added. Similar to a WordPress page where the user can create new pages and SEO will automatically work.

Comment: In that case, Gatsby doesn't fit your requeriments

Comment: Thats what I thought from reading over the docs. Probably SSR is the way to go.